# Add delay to several div's on page load

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add some delay to an animation to a div, but when the page is loaded div's three, four and five display immediately but div one and two display correctly, am I not able to add the delay in this method?

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#one").addClass('animated fadeInUp');

        $("#two").delay(300).addClass('animated fadeInUp');
        $("#three").delay(600).addClass('animated fadeInUp');
        $("#four").delay(900).addClass('animated fadeInUp');
        $("#five").delay(1200).addClass('animated fadeInUp');

    });

</script>
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you use any animation js like wow.js?

Comment: Yes, I am using animate.css